# "Save console output to log file" doesn't work in IDEA

Tags: intellij-idea, logging

When I open a run configuration in IDEA and specify a log file (Tab **Logs** -> **Save console output to log file**)
and run the app the log file won't be created.
The file path is valid.

I've checked access permissions of the directory in which the file should be created - it's writable.
I've even run

```
chmod a+rwx -R
```

on it before executing the app.

What can go wrong? Does this option work fine usually?

Comment: is there anything relevant in idea.log (Help | Show logs...)?

Comment: @PetrRastegaev 
I've looked for the folder or the log file name in
~/.cache/JetBrains/IntelliJIdea2020.1/log
but there haven't been any matches

Comment: @PetrRastegaev not sure what happened but IDEA began to write to the log file. I didn't change any related settings.